# Sort custom struct with date information

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to sorting my custom struct with values of date in my RLMResult. Here, what i do:

Created a RLMSortDescriptor with each values of date that i have and than used sortedResults method with descriptor parameters, but method sort my date in wrong order. Maybe you know some better way to do that?

Here is my code:

```
func sortParametrs(sortState: SortingActionState, sortedParametr: String) {
        var result = false
        if sortState == .sortedAtGreatest {
            result = false
        } else {
            result = true
        }
        if sortedParametr == "date" {
            let sortDate = [RLMSortDescriptor(keyPath: "nearestPlan.date.day", ascending: result), RLMSortDescriptor(keyPath: "nearestPlan.date.month", ascending: result)]
            parentViewController.logic?.filteredFarms = parentViewController.logic?.getFarms()?.sortedResults(using: sortDate)
        } else {
            parentViewController.logic?.filteredFarms = parentViewController.logic?.getFarms()?.sortedResults(usingKeyPath: sortedParametr, ascending: result)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you should post the code that you tried.

Comment: Yeah, I edited question.

Comment: In addition, _"this is not work"_ is not a problem description. Presumably you meant that the records were sorted but in a wrong, seemingly arbitrary order?

Comment: I change "problem" in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this use

```
let sortDate = [RLMSortDescriptor(keyPath: "nearestPlan.date.year", ascending: result), RLMSortDescriptor(keyPath: "nearestPlan.date.month", ascending: result), RLMSortDescriptor(keyPath: "nearestPlan.date.day", ascending: result)]
```

instead

```
let sortDate = [RLMSortDescriptor(keyPath: "nearestPlan.date.day", ascending: result), RLMSortDescriptor(keyPath: "nearestPlan.date.month", ascending: result)]
```

location of this parameters is important)